# Ackermann Decision Problem

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, decision-problem

I have been studying the [Ackermann function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/AckermannFunction.html), specifically the two-argument Ackermann–Péter version.

With the Ackermann function, I developed a problem I call the "Ackermann Decision Problem"

> Given non-negative integers, x and y, does A(x,x) = y?

The naive solution to verify the Ackermann Decision Problem would be to compute the Ackermann Function. From my research, I seem to be unable to find a way to compute the Ackermann Function in polynomial time.

Is this problem in NP?

Is the time complexity for verifying and solving the Ackermann Decision Problem the same?

Comment: You only need to compute the Ackermann function in time polynomial on the length of the answer. It seems to me that you can do this using Knuth-arrow definitions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function#Definition

Comment: And you don’t have to compute it, only show that it is larger than y in that time. You stop as soon as you know A(x) is too large.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don’t need to compute the Ackerman function to verify this at all.

The problem is trivial for x <= 3. And for x >= 4, if you can write down y, then the answer is “no”.

More serious, if you actually wrote down say y ≈ A(4), you can solve it easily in linear time in the size of y. If calculating A(4) takes more time than that then you know it is greater than y and stop calculating.

PS. This is a question/answer site, not a free proof writing service.

Comment: I cannot see how "you don’t need to compute the Ackerman function to verify this *at all*". I don't see any relevance of $A(4)$ to this question on computational complexity, which is about the asymptotic behavior when the length of input goes to infinity. $A(4)$ is just one number.

Comment: Well, go through my post and find what becomes wrong when you replace A(4) with A(5). The point stands that if you can write y then it isn't equal to A(4). And in a hypothetical world where you wrote down a number y huge enough that it _might_ be A(k) for some k ≥ 4, deciding that A(k) = y takes only linear time in the size of y.

Comment: While your conclusion might be right, where is the justification? This answer does not use any property of Ackermann function except that $A(x,x)$ is large relative to $x$. Have you *proved* linear time is enough?

Comment: How would you justify for example if I replace $A(x,x)$ with $\sqrt{A(x,x)}$? Or $A(x,x)/A(x-1,x-1)$?

Comment: Both are easy enough to calculate in time proportional to the size of the answer, and it's easy enough to show that one of these expressions is much greater than y without calculating it, if indeed it is much greater.

Comment: Please show it, especially when "it is easy enough".

Comment: There are two types of math/cs propositions that are particular interesting. One type is that it looks very easy/very obviously true to some people (with trained eyes), which might be, however, not easy to prove.

Comment: Once again, I am asking for a **proof**. I am not saying at all that I don't believe your conclusion that linear time is enough.

Comment: John, you can hold your breath until I waste my time on writing a proof on your say so. It’s trivial. Do it yourself.

Comment: @JohnL.: despite your claims, gnasher's answer is smart. But the question cannot be answered as long as we don't know how $y$ is supplied.

Comment: Hi Yves, i think it is still easy even if you use some non-standard notation like Knuth’s up arrows. The only difference is there is a chance that x is too small :-) (It would be quite a bit of work, but all straightforward).